# Ionic row on click

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic4

I have ionic rows which is created with the value of the loop. On that loop when I click I want to open another row but in place of an opening row of a particular row, all the rows are opening.

```
 <ion-grid [hidden]="!destination" (click)="onButtonClick()" *ngFor="let vehicle of vehicles; let i = index" [ngClass]="{'active': vehicle.active}"
    (click)="chooseVehicle(i)"  >

  <ion-row class="card" >
    <ion-col> <img src="{{ vehicle.icon }}"> </ion-col>
    <ion-col> <p class="carName">{{ vehicle.name }}</p> </ion-col>
    <ion-col> <p class="carSeats">{{ vehicle.seats }} seats</p> </ion-col>
<!--    <ion-col> <p class="carPrice">{{currency }}{{ vehicle.fee_taxed }}</p> </ion-col> -->

 </ion-row>
 <ion-row *ngIf="buttonClicked">
     <ion-col><p class="carPrice">{{ vehicle.name }}</p></ion-col>
     <ion-col> <p class="carSeats">{{ vehicle.seats }} seats</p> </ion-col>
     
</ion-row>
 
</ion-grid>
```

[As you can see in image rows for both sedan and SUV is opening in down I only want to open one which is selected please guide me](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bEevk.png)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46356551/how-to-make-ion-grid-clickable-like-button-in-ionic-2
Maybe you can click the link above

Answer (score 0):

I don't know much about ionic but when I read the documentation and from HyperCreeck comment you can do something like this on html file :

```
<ion-grid *ngFor="let vehicle of vehicles; let i = index">
  <ion-row (click)="showDetail(vehicle)">
    <ion-col> {{ vehicle.name }} </ion-col>
    <ion-col>{{ vehicle.seat }} seats</ion-col>
  </ion-row>

 <ion-row *ngIf="vehicle.show">
     <ion-col>{{ vehicle.name }}</ion-col>
     <ion-col>{{ vehicle.seat }} seats</ion-col>
     <ion-col>{{ vehicle.price }}</ion-col>
  </ion-row>
 
</ion-grid>
```

on ts file :

```
//I assume your data something like bellow 
     vehicles = [
        {
          'name' : 'sedan' ,
          'seat' : '4',
          'price': '¥100.000'
        },
        {
          'name' : 'suv',
          'seat' : '4',
          'price': '¥100.000',
        },
        {
          'name' : 'ferari',
          'seat' : '2',
          'price': '¥100.000',
        }
      ]

constructor(){
    for (let index = 0; index < this.vehicles.length; index++) {
      const element = this.vehicles[index];
      element['show'] = false;
    }
  }

showDetail(item: any) {
    if (item.show == true) {
      item.show = false;
    } else {
      item.show = true;
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do as per below also:

```
<ion-grid [hidden]="!destination" *ngFor="let vehicle of vehicles; let i = index" [ngClass]="{'active': vehicle.active}"
 >

<ion-row class="card"  (click)="chooseVehicle(i)">
<ion-col> <img src="{{ vehicle.icon }}"> </ion-col>
<ion-col> <p class="carName">{{ vehicle.name }}</p> </ion-col>
<ion-col> <p class="carSeats">{{ vehicle.seats }} seats</p> </ion-col>
<!--    <ion-col> <p class="carPrice">{{currency }}{{ vehicle.fee_taxed }}</p> 
</ion-col> -->

</ion-row>
 <ion-row *ngIf="i == selectedVechicleIndex">
 <ion-col><p class="carPrice">{{ vehicle.name }}</p></ion-col>
 <ion-col> <p class="carSeats">{{ vehicle.seats }} seats</p> </ion-col>
 
  </ion-row>

  </ion-grid>
```

And on ts file do like below:

first, take one variable above to constructor:

```
 selectedVechicleIndex = 0
```

then

```
  chooseVehicle(i){
  if(i == this.selectedVechicleIndex){

  this.selectedVechicleIndex = 0
  } else {
  this.selectedVechicleIndex = i
  }   
  }
```

Using above code you show and hide row as per your requirement.